# show the listItem related information from database on ListItemclick on new Activity

Tags: android

I am making one Android Application and I am Stuck at One Point and need help for it.

I have the List Of Doctors. each list row contains only DoctorName and Speciality.

I want to show each Doctors Information Like his Address,Phone number etc.on its ItemClick in new Layout.

How to Pass this two Parameters(DocName,Speciality) through onItemClickListner() according to Position using Intent to Open my New Activity(DoctorInfo)

How to retrive that text value of DoctorName of each row which i Select using setOnItemClickListner()

how to resolve it???

**this is my listner method**

```
lstDoctorList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int                position, long id) {
                String DocName = view.findViewById(R.id.txtDoctorName).;// I want Solution for this Line
               Intent i = new Intent(DoctorsActivity.this,DoctorInfo.class);
               i.putExtra("DocName",DocName);
               startActivity(i);
           }
       });
```

How I will get DoctorName to Pass my New Activity???

Comment: Use  `Intent` to pass data between the activities.

Comment: I want Only DoctorName on Clicking the row .How do i get that from setOnItemClickListener()

Comment: I have added the code for you. Please check it and do a research before asking simple questions :)

Comment: I think u didnt understand my question..I just wanted to know,How to retrieve DoctorName accordig to its Position????

Comment: @prakshi check my edited answer.

Comment: please post your java class or if you are using adapter class then post it

Comment: @prakshi refer this demo: http://javatechig.com/android/pass-a-data-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android

Comment: @Damini  thank you.this link is very useful for me..:)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass data from one activity to another activity :

```
ListView listView = getListView();

            // listening to single list item on click
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {

                  // selected item
                HERE YOU GOT POSITION FOR PARTICULAR ITEM

                  // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
               Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),       ActivityToLaunch.class);
                 intent.putExtra("DOCTOR_NAME", here get the doctor name from your list using the position arg);
                 startActivity(intent);

              }
            });`
```

And in ActivityToLaunch

`Intent intent = getIntent();
 String getDoctorName = intent.getStringExtra("DOCTOR_NAME");`

Comment: this thing i Know..what I want to know  that How to retrieve the value of "doctorName" from each listrow

Comment: Edited. check it now.

Comment: @prakshi check my answer

Comment: refere this demo:  http://javatechig.com/android/pass-a-data-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android

Answer (score 0):

in your setOnItemClickListener()

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Doctorname", DocName);
startActivity(intent);
```

get intent in your second activity:

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  String dn = intent.getStringExtra("Doctorname");
```

Comment: I know this..I want to know how to retrieve DocName for each row according to position..????

Comment: you are using adapter class for listview